# Replacing UserScripts.org URLs with new mirror

Tags: support, hyperlinks

UserScripts.org [went finally down a while ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260391/now-that-userscripts-org-is-essentially-dead-is-any-action-required-for-link-on?__=1971454841), and there are some undeleted questions at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fuserscripts.org) and [Web Apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fuserscripts.org) (few at Apple and Ubuntu, maybe others) using the URLs.

Now, looks like there's kind of an "official"  mirror at [userscripts-mirror.org](http://userscripts-mirror.org/). There's no [WHOIS information](https://who.is/whois/userscripts-mirror.org), but I found [this Redit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/userscripts/comments/27gw9z/seems_like_usercriptsorg8080_has_died_i_have_just/) from, apparently, the domain owner. That doesn't matter much, but we have a dead domain floating around, and a live one that may or may not be long among the living.

The old URLs

```javascript
http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/SCRIPT-ID
```

are mirrored at

```javascript
http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/review/SCRIPT-ID.html
```

Is it worthy doing a search/replace? Human or machine made?

<sub>*I just saw that **the Web Archive [has stuff mirrored](http://web.archive.org/web/20131116203715/http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/58023)**. Much better than an anon-whois.*</sub>

Comment: You're free to replace the URLs with a mirror URL if you run across them, but I doubt Stack Exchange is going to run a database search query to replace URLs with an unofficial mirror with no WHOIS information.

Comment: Ok, that makes a nice answer! Because, yes, I ran across them and did a couple of replaces.

Comment: Note: if the script has since found a new home at https://greasyfork.org, point the URL there instead.

Comment: Mmmm, I just updated the question with the Web Archive option, @Martijn, looks like it's better to do it Human Made and decide on each case. The number at SO gotta be around five hundred.